# Jquery statement that won't J

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me with my jquery statement...

I have a 'share' box - on submit I want to 'force' the 'share' (user, date and message) to the screen below my cl_share_hide_me class ...so that the user does not have to reload the page to see his/her share.

I have gotten this far but not able to go further

Merci!

```
    <span class='cl_share_hide_me'>
          <br />
            <textarea spellcheck='false' class='class_share_a_post' rows="3" cols="58"  id='slick-show'></textarea>
               <br/>
                <br />
            <input type='submit' value='Share' class='cl_share_button' data-share-nid= "2749" data-share-type="field_school" /><br />
            <br />

    </span>





        var sometext = "<div class='shared_content_background'> oy voy</div>";

        var placeToPutData = $(this).parent().parent().find('.cl_share_hide_me');

        placeToPutData.after(sometext);
```

Comment: You html is not valid, try using a block element like `div` instead of `span`.

Answer (score 0):

in chrome try using console.log(placeToPutData) to make sure you're finding what you're looking for.  Alternatively you should be able to just do

```
$('.sl_share_hide_me').after(sometext)
```

If there is only one instane of it on the page this should work for you.

Comment: No there are many instances - I need to show up only on the post that is being shared

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong... For starters you don't have a `<script>` tag around your js. `$(this)` is not defined. And it should be like this

```
<script>
    var sometext = "<div class='shared_content_background'> oy voy</div>";
    $('.cl_share_hide_me').after(sometext);
</script>
```